# Implement K-fold cross validation in MLPClassification Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am learning how to develop a Backpropagation Neural Network using scikit-learn. I still confuse with how to implement k-fold cross validation in my neural network. I wish you guys can help me out. My code is as follow:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

f = open("seeds_dataset.txt")
data = np.loadtxt(f)

X=data[:,0:]
y=data[:,-1]
kf = KFold(n_splits=10)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[train], X[test], y[train], y[test]
clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1)
clf.fit(X, y)
MLPClassifier(activation='relu', alpha=1e-05, batch_size='auto',
       beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=False,
       epsilon=1e-08, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), learning_rate='constant',
       learning_rate_init=0.001, max_iter=200, momentum=0.9,
       nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5, random_state=1, shuffle=True,
       solver='lbfgs', tol=0.0001, validation_fraction=0.1, verbose=False,
       warm_start=False)
```

Comment: I think your intent is that you want to do the kfold splits and also the scoring. You could use [`cross_val_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html). It'll do the Kfold for you while also generating the list of scores.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do not split your data into train and test. This is automatically handled by the KFold cross-validation.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kf = KFold(n_splits=10)
clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1)

for train_indices, test_indices in kf.split(X):
    clf.fit(X[train_indices], y[train_indices])
    print(clf.score(X[test_indices], y[test_indices]))
```

KFold validation partitions your dataset into n equal, fair portions. Each portion is then split into test and train. With this, you get a fairly accurate measure of the accuracy of your model since it is tested on small portions of fairly distributed data.

Comment: My prediction accuracy is 0% I dont know what I did wrong for that

Comment: @Trung With the code? No. I've used this to good effect in the past. You possibly have issues with your data. Check to make sure that `X` and `y` have the same length, and that each value in `X[i]` corresponds to `y[i]`. Put print statements to check.

Comment: You can also try `clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1, verbose=True)` and see what it prints during training.

Comment: You can also change the solver to `adam` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Coldpseed Thank, it worked when I change it to adam. I think my hidden layer sizes is wrong. I will check on this. Again, thank you so much for your help

Comment: Just remember that the solver's performance is largely affected by not only the data but your hyper-params. Experiment a lot till you find the best combo. There is no 1-fits-all solution to these problems. Cheers.

Comment: And I think you need to set `warm_start=True` From the doc: When set to True, reuse the solution of the previous call to fit as initialization, otherwise, just erase the previous solution.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are looking for already built in method to do this, you can take a look at [cross_validate](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html).

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate 

model = MLPClassifier() 
cv_results = cross_validate(model, X, Y, cv=10, 
                            return_train_score=False, 
                            scoring=model.score) 
print("Fit scores: {}".format(cv_results['test_score']))
```

The thing I like about this approach is it gives you access to the fit_time, score_time, and test_score. It also allows you to supply your choice of scoring metrics and cross-validation generator/iterable (i.e. Kfold). Another good resource is [Cross Validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#the-cross-validate-function-and-multiple-metric-evaluation).

Answer (score 3):

Kudos to @COLDSPEED's answer.

If you'd like to have the prediction of n fold cross-validation, cross_val_predict() is the way to go.

```
# Scamble and subset data frame into train + validation(80%) and test(10%)
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
train_index = 0.8
df_train = df[ : len(df) * train_index]

# convert dataframe to ndarray, since kf.split returns nparray as index
feature = df_train.iloc[:, 0: -1].values
target = df_train.iloc[:, -1].values

solver = MLPClassifier(activation='relu', solver='adam', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1, verbose=True)
y_pred = cross_val_predict(solver, feature, target, cv = 10)
```

Basically, the option cv indicates how many cross-validation you'd like to do in the training. y_pred is the same size as target.